# How to do something like 'index(match)' on parallel output

Tags: python, csv, data-analysis

My apologies if I seem stupid. I tried googling and searching but maybe I cannot formulate the right sentences because I cannot exactly get what I want out of it.

I have a CSV table

```
A   B   C
AA  BA  CA
AB  BB  CB
AC  BC  CC
```

I want to make it so that I input "AB" and Python will return data from BOTH Column A and Column B(AB is BB).

Anyone can show a sample code for me, please?

Comment: Can you give example if the user input "AC" or just "C"?. Not sure what you really need.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our sample CSV file:

```
with open('test.csv','w',newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(['A','B','C'])
    csvwriter.writerow(['AA','BA','CA'])
    csvwriter.writerow(['AB','BB','CB'])
    csvwriter.writerow(['AC','BC','CC'])
```

A simple way of getting what you need, is to turn it into a dictionary when you read it, this way you can simply use column headers to access your data:

```
with open('test.csv', newline= '') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row['A'] == 'AB':
            print(row['A'],row['B'])
```

Without knowing more, it is difficult to provide more guidance.

Comment: No, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!!